# Importing images using subfloats in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am using subfloats to import 2 .png files in a figure to basically generate subfigures. There's no space between the figures when I compile it. How do I put some white space in between them? And is it possible to convert them to black and white using LaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

Try `\vskip 1em` between the figures.  If this doesn't work, post your nonworking figure code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

To put white space in between them, you can throw a `\quad`—or anything that makes whitespace—in between the subfloats within the figure. Converting to grayscale is not in the graphicx package as far as I can see; all the literature on it says to use an external program. My first instinct is to explore TikZ (a LaTeX package) just because it is so powerful, but I have no idea if it can do anything with external graphics. [This Page](http://chem-bla-ics.blogspot.com/2008/01/my-phd-thesis-in-color-and-grayscale.html) deals with compile time options to specify a grayscale or color version. For example, if you have all the color images in one folder, you batch convert them to grayscale and put them in a separate folder with identical filenames. Then, at compile time, specify from which folder to get the images. See the comments for the `graphicspath` implementation.

Comment: I think TikZ is overkill for this problem.